Hide Different sets of columns based off of checkboxes with formulas
Using Google sheets, I would like to hide a certain set of columns if a certain checkbox is checked. I want to do this for multiple sets of columns and multiple checkboxes. The checkboxes are checked based off a formula that references another cell.
For example:
If A1 checkbox is checked, I want to hide column I:L. If A2 checkbox is checked, I want to hide column N:Q, and so forth. In addition, all the checkboxes in column A get checked or unchecked depending if the cell in the same row in column B has any text in it.
I have the follow script written:
function onEdit(e) {
  let col = 0;
  switch(e.range.getA1Notation()) {
    case "A1":
      col = 9;
      break;
    case "A2":
      col = 14;
      break;
    case "A3":
      col = 19;
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
  if( e.value === "FALSE" ) {
    e.source.getActiveSheet().hideColumns(col,4)
  }
  else {
    e.source.getActiveSheet().showColumns(col,4)
  }
}

The problem with this script is, it depends on checkbox cells being changed to "False" by unchecking the checkbox. Since the checkbox has a formula to check or uncheck it, it does not trigger the script to go in to affect. If I delete the checkbox formula and manual check or uncheck it, the script will work properly. The text in column B get populated depending on a drop selection in C1. I would love to trigger this column hiding script every time the dropdown is switched.
To recap:
A dropdown in C1 is selected.
Column B gets populated depending on which dropdown selection is made.
Checkboxes in Column A get checked if the is any text in the cells of column B. This is auto executed by a formula set up for each checkbox cell.
If the checkbox in A1 is unchecked, I want columns I:L to be hidden. If checkbox in A2 is unchecked, I want columns N:Q hidden, and so forth.
I want this to be triggered any time a different dropdown is selected.
Thanks!

Welcome to SO! Your question could be much clearer (and shorter) with a text table of what your data looks like, and a sample sheet that you can share anonymously with this tool.

Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

The only reason I didn’t share my sheet is due to sensitive work information.

I don't understand your recap can you please create a minimal reproducible example.

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

As per The Master's comment, we don't want your proprietary data. If you have a problem that only occurs with some data, we want the simplest data that will demonstrate the problem, together with simple but similar data that doesn't demonstrate the problem. Actually here's an example with sample data.

Simple triggers only run when activated by a user:

The onEdit(e) trigger runs automatically when a user changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet.

So the range of the edit event e.range will never be a cell in column A, if they're (un)ticked automatically via a formula. Other than that, your code looked good.
You just need to check that the edited cell is indeed C1, in which case you can just go through each tickbox to see whether they're checked, and (un)hide the columns accordingly.
The following code should do what you want:
function onEdit(e) {
  let col = 9;
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() !== "C1") {
    return;
  }
  for (let i=0; i<3; i++, col+=5) {
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 1).getValue() ?
      sheet.showColumns(col, 4) :
      sheet.hideColumns(col, 4);
  }
}

How it works:

if the edited cell is not C1, it stops;
if it is, it checks each cell in column A from row i+1=1 to row i+1=3, in this case (but you can obviously change that);
for each cell in column A, hide or unhide 4 columns - depending on its value, using the ternary operator: starting at column 9 in the case of A1, and advancing in steps of 5 thereon.

References

Ternary operator


Thank you for the response! I tried the script but it seems like it hides more than just sets of columns without checks. I attached a link to a dummy document. There are some minor differences from what I originally posted.  For instance, The dropdown is in B4, not C1. You can see the checkboxes in Column A. If the checkbox in A30 is not checked, I want columns I:L hidden. If A31 is unchecked, I want N:Q hidden, and so on. I want this to run any time a different dropdown selection is made. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ip9BhivTx1P63JgilFHSyAdwoprEDMXCpWnpTRfo-U4/edit?usp=sharing
